# Can't select full line?

Tags: c#, .net

```
 int startchar = textCenter.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
 int currentline = textCenter.GetLineFromCharIndex(startchar);

 string currentlinetext = textCenter.Lines[currentline];

 textCenter.Select(startchar, currentlinetext.Length);
```

When I click a button named idButton, I have it search through a richtextbox, and find what is entered in idTextBox.

This all works fine. From there I wish to have the entire line selected from where the idText is found. When this begins, it only selects a first group of characters.

Some lines will be completely selected, where as other will only select 20 characters, 17 characters, 22 characters, etc.

It seems to be completely random as to how many characters are actually selected, and I have searched for quite some time now, trying to find a way to select all characters in the line, yet nothing seems to help. Any help would be appreciated.

The lines would be ordered somewhat as follows: (took out last names)

```
111570 Zack Downs
111573 Alexys --
111574 Corey --
111575 Dylan --
etc.
```

The text entered in to idBox would be the ID refering to each student in my district, and I would like the program to search through these individual lines for the students name.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should change your code to

```
textCenter.Select(startchar, currentlinetext.Length - startchar + 1);
```

to select (in currentline) till the end of the row, not more.
**Example:** if your line is made of 30 chars and you start selecting from 7th, you must select 24 chars, not 30.

Comment: I am sorry for the very delayed response, I can only really work on this project between 8am and 9:30am EST. Your suggestion sadly did not work as planned. it now selects every line in the rich textbox starting at the startchar + 1. I have also clarified something in the original post, at the end if you care to check it out.